# How to increase the accuracy of my predictions (CNN fine tuning VGG16 KERAS)

Tags: python, keras, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, vgg16

In my VGG16 fine-tuning, I have to classify retinal images in 2 classes (or 4th stage or not 4th stage) and I have 700 images each class to train. This is my code now:

```py
TRAIN_DIR = 'train/'
TEST_DIR = 'test/'
v = 'v/'
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHS = 5

def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()
    classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = [f for f in os.listdir(Path) if not f.startswith('.')]

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        for index, Image in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
            # Convert the path into a file
            ImageCV.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image), (224,224)))
            #ImageCV[index]= np.array(ImageCV[index]) / 255.0
            LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0])) 

            #ImageCV[index] = cv2.addWeighted(ImageCV[index],4, cv2.GaussianBlur(ImageCV[index],(0,0), 10), -4, 128)
            image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(ImageCV[index], (0, 0), 100 / 30)
            ImageCV[index] = cv2.addWeighted(ImageCV[index], 4, image_blurred, -4, 128)



    return ImageCV, LabelList

data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)
valid, vlabels = ReadImages(TEST_DIR)

vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=True)

# (1) visualize layers
print("VGG16 model layers")
for i, layer in enumerate(vgg16_model.layers):
    print(i, layer.name, layer.output_shape)

# (2) remove the top layer
base_model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, 
                   output=vgg16_model.get_layer("block5_pool").output)

# (3) attach a new top layer
base_out = base_model.output
base_out = Reshape((25088,))(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dropout(0.5)(base_out)
# output layer: (None, 5)
top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc1)

# (4) freeze weights until the last but one convolution layer (block4_pool)
for layer in base_model.layers[0:14]:
    layer.trainable = False

# (5) create new hybrid model
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=top_preds)

# (6) compile and train the model
sgd = SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(data)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1)

# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(np.array(data), np.array(labels), batch_size=32), 
                    steps_per_epoch=len(np.array(data)) / 32, epochs=15,
                    validation_data=(np.array(valid), np.array(vlabels)),
                    nb_val_samples=72, callbacks=[es])


model.save('model.h5')
```

This model, in 4 epochs, gets a accuracy of 1.00 with a minimal loss (~0.01), but when I try to run the predict.py in some test images, the REAL accuracy is about 50% (in 10 images, the app answers correctly only 5).
This is my predict. py:

```py
model = load_model('model.h5')

for filename in os.listdir(r'v/'):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".ppm") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        ImageCV = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(TEST_DIR) + filename), (224,224))
        #ImageCV = cv2.addWeighted(ImageCV,4, cv2.GaussianBlur(ImageCV,(0,0), 224/25), -4, 120)
        #ImageCV = ImageCV.reshape(-1,224,224,3)

        x = image.img_to_array(ImageCV)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        #print(model.predict(x))

        prob = model.predict(x)
        if prob < 0.5:
            print("nonPDR")
        else:
            print("PDR")
        print(filename)
```

**THINGS I'VE TRIED:**

- change LR 
- put dense(256) layer before dropout
- increase dropout to 0.75
- change some dataAugmentation parameters

The input will be images like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgGh1.jpg
To be better to classificate, i'm refining my image in ReadImages method: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1F3k.png

So, what can I do to improve my accuracy REALLY in my predictions and not only in the train and accuracy values?

There's something I've been making wrong?

### UPDATE

I've drop out the gaussianblur I was using in ReadImages, and included the follow:

```py
data = np.asarray(data)
valid = np.asarray(valid)

data = data.astype('float32')
valid = valid.astype('float32')

data /= 255
valid /= 255
```

And after run my train.py:

```
Epoch 1/15

44/43 [==============================] - 476s 11s/step - loss: 0.7153 - acc: 0.5788 - val_loss: 0.6937 - val_acc: 0.5556

Epoch 2/15

44/43 [==============================] - 468s 11s/step - loss: 0.5526 - acc: 0.7275 - val_loss: 0.6838 - val_acc: 0.5833

Epoch 3/15

44/43 [==============================] - 474s 11s/step - loss: 0.5068 - acc: 0.7595 - val_loss: 0.6927 - val_acc: 0.5694

Epoch 00003: early stopping
```

After, I update the std and mean on predict.py:

```py
for filename in os.listdir(r'v/'):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".ppm") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        ImageCV = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(TEST_DIR) + filename), (224,224))

        ImageCV = np.asarray(ImageCV)

        ImageCV = ImageCV.astype('float32')

        ImageCV /= 255  
        x = ImageCV

        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = normalize(x, [0.12810835, 0.17897758, 0.23883381], [0.14304605, 0.18229756, 0.2362126])

        prob = model.predict(x)
        if prob <= 0.50:
            print("nonPDR >>>", filename)
            nonPdr += 1
        else:
            print("PDR >>>", filename)
            pdr += 1
        print(prob)
print("Number of retinas with PDR: ",pdr)
print("Number of retinas without PDR: ",nonPdr)
```

And after run this code, I'm getting roughly 75% accuracy in my test dir..

So, can I improve something, or this is the maximum for these tiny number of images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following suggestions.

1. Make sure your preprocess function in `predict.py` is doing exactly what `datagen` is doing during training (featurewise_center and normalization)
2. For Sigmoid value greater than 0.5 is defined as class 1 and value less than or **equal** is defined as class 0. In your code, for values exactly same as 0.5 are being assigned in class 1 which should not be the case.

For point 2, you may argue why this equality will make a difference. Most of the time in sigmoid due to some reason the sigmoid value for class 0 comes as exact 0.5 which especially I have seen in segmentation tasks.

Edit: To ensure that image is processed in same way as the training images are processed use keras generator only

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=True,
            samplewise_std_normalization=True)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        args.validate_dir,  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(512, 512),  
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True)
```

Now `test_generator.next()` will return X,Y pair which can be used for prediction checks.

I have ignored rotations and all from ImageDataGenerator as they are not changing the image properties like featurewise_center is changing.

Comment: How can I make in predict the same as in train?

Comment: Check the answer now.

Comment: Great answer, but i'm not understanding how to apply it in my project.. The code you've posted is on predict.py? I have to write my gaussian blur too?

Comment: Use ReadImage method in predict.py as well. Also yes, the code I have posted is for predict.py.  Hope I am being helpful.

Comment: see my update, please

Comment: For further improvement, check preprocessing funtion used by http://blog.kaggle.com/2015/09/09/diabetic-retinopathy-winners-interview-1st-place-ben-graham/